# .sh installation error, this script is to be run as resolve user

Tags: 14.04, scripts, xterm, .sh

Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.
I downloaded a .sh file that is supposed to install Davinci resolve but when i run it it says uncompressing installation package, and then says this script is supposed to be run as the resolve user. Please login as the resolve user and run this script again. I have no idea what i am supposed to login to. I am not very experienced with Ubuntu. Davinci resolve is a video editing software, This is where i downloaded it http://goo.gl/09wCz3

[image: Screenshot of the terminal]

Comment: Did you create a user called "resolve"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software is designed to run only on a custom Linux built for it, so there is no way to install it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Script telling you that you must run it as `resolve` user. This means that you should create user `resolve`, and run installation as this user.

```
$ sudo useradd -d /home/resolve -s /bin/bash -m resolve
```

Now move you install file to /home/resolve, and give permissions for resolve:resolve

```
$ chown resolve:resolve yourfile
```

Switch in terminal to this user: `sudo su resolve`, and run installation as you do it before.

I don't know what is Davinci Resolve and how use it, may be you do not need `HOME` directory for you user, and you only need user. In that case run

```
$ sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -M resolve
```

This will not create home folder

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, so I gave up.